# Excessive Bass in 5.1 Center Channel

Tags: 12.04, sound

Recently upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 and my sound is goofy, I don't remember it sounding this off before the upgrade.  I've got some basic Logitech Z506 speakers hooked up to the analogue outs on the sound card and I'm using the Analogue 5.1 option on the default Sound dialogue in System Settings.

It seems like there is way too much bass in the center channel and almost none coming thru the subwoofer for some reason.

> [Intel ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDA Intel at 0xf9df8000 irq 77 1 [NVidia ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia HDA NVidia at 0xfbbfc000 irq 34

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: :~$ gedit /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xf9df8000 irq 77
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfbbfc000 irq 34

Comment: I'm struggling with my sound too. I wish there was a mixer to adjust bass.

Comment: This question is about 11.10 to 12.04 upgrade both of which are EOL. The question has no answers in 5+ years. VTC as `not reproducible`.